# Gracefully restarting explorer.exe as of Windows 10 1709, Fall Creators Update aka Redstone 3

Tags: c#, windows-10, registry, explorer

For the current version of Windows 10, 1703, the Creators Update, I have this little C# app getting called to restart explorer.exe during an installation sequence. This is to help refresh the taskbar/registry entries, so that one of the virtual peripherals will appear on the taskbar after installation without rebooting.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace RestartExplorer
{
    class Program
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            var process = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")[0];
            process.Kill();
            Process.Start("explorer");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

This was working fine in Redstone 2, but in the current Insiders Preview Windows 10 1709 Redstone 3 build of `16294.1.170916-2023`, it doesn't just kill the explorer shell, it kills *all* the open file explorer windows too. That's super invasive, and if I had a couple dozen windows open while working when that happened, I don't think I'd be very happy about the UX.

I verified that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>Right-Click</kbd> on the Taskbar for ***Exit Explorer*** also shows the same diverging behavior, not just my little app.

So, if I want to make sure my users' windows aren't all lost, how should I now be restarting explorer, or better yet, is there an even better way to get the end-result for what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Yikes! That's not good... at least not this close to RTM it's not! lol. I submitted a bug through the dev center, but I'm not going to cross my fingers for a fix in RedStone 3. If it happens, cool.

Comment: @itsme86 I don't think it is. In RedStone 2, you have at least 2 `explorer.exe` instances running when you have your file explorer opened. In RedStone 3, there's only one `explorer.exe` instance. Ergo, killing the one and only explorer instance kills all the windows that were opened. Besides open file explorer windows, and your clipboard, do you know what might be lost when killing the entire `explorer.exe`? I'm trying to think of how to write a recovery module as a workaround.

Comment: "it kills all the open windows too." Do you mean it kills "all windows" or "all file explorer windows"? I thought you were talking about the former.

Comment: @itsme86 File explorer windows.

Comment: Oh, well that makes sense then.

Comment: I don't think there's any straightforward way to do this anymore in Windows 10. It will probably need a list of all entities affected before killing/restarting explorer, and trying to restore them to that state after explorer is running again. Perhaps the session restart manager solutions shared below could be a starting point, but it's not going to be enough to use `GetProcessesByName`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the restart manager API to close all open explorers. It will restart any that were closed.  Only downside is that restarted apps will be activated so you have to code around your app losing focus.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373649(v=vs.85).aspx

```
var sessionKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
NativeMethods.RmStartSession(out IntPtr session, 0, sessionKey).CheckError();
try
{
    NativeMethods.RmRegisterResources(session, 1, new[] { Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows), "explorer.exe") }, 0, null, 0, null).CheckError();
    NativeMethods.RmShutdown(session, 0, null).CheckError();
    NativeMethods.RmRestart(session, 0, null).CheckError();
}
finally
{
    NativeMethods.RmEndSession(session);
}
```

You will also need the following NativeMethods

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS
    {
        public int dwProcessId;
        public com.FILETIME ProcessStartTime;
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum RM_SHUTDOWN_TYPE : uint
    {
        RmForceShutdown = 0x1,
        RmShutdownOnlyRegistered = 0x10
    }

    internal delegate void RM_WRITE_STATUS_CALLBACK(UInt32 nPercentComplete);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int RmStartSession(out IntPtr pSessionHandle, int dwSessionFlags, string strSessionKey);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll")]
    internal static extern int RmEndSession(IntPtr pSessionHandle);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    internal static extern int RmRegisterResources(IntPtr pSessionHandle, UInt32 nFiles, string[] rgsFilenames, UInt32 nApplications, RM_UNIQUE_PROCESS[] rgApplications, UInt32 nServices, string[] rgsServiceNames);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll")]
    internal static extern int RmShutdown(IntPtr pSessionHandle, RM_SHUTDOWN_TYPE lActionFlags, RM_WRITE_STATUS_CALLBACK fnStatus);

    [DllImport("rstrtmgr.dll")]
    internal static extern int RmRestart(IntPtr pSessionHandle, int dwRestartFlags, RM_WRITE_STATUS_CALLBACK fnStatus);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    internal static extern bool GetProcessTimes(IntPtr hProcess, out com.FILETIME lpCreationTime, out com.FILETIME lpExitTime, out com.FILETIME lpKernelTime, out com.FILETIME lpUserTime);
}
```

Comment: If you provide a compileable sample, I'll take a look at this. As-written, I can't do much with it. This answer relies on missing inference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the @Tim code and for providing a more usable example here is the class I just wrote for interacting with Restart Manager:

https://gist.github.com/falahati/34b23831733151460de1368c5fba8e93

Here is an example:

```
using RestartManager;

public static class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (var rm = new RestartManagerSession())
        {
            // add all processes having the name `explorer`
            rm.RegisterProcess(Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"));

            // you can also add explorer.exe specifically by 
            // using the `RegisterProcessFile()` method
            //rm.RegisterProcessFile(new FileInfo(Path.Combine(
            //  Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows),
            //  "explorer.exe"
            //)));

            rm.Shutdown(RestartManagerSession.ShutdownType.Normal);
            rm.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can also use the following piece of code to get Explorer's main process in case you want to be more specific:

```
[DllImport("user32")]
private static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();

[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr windowHandle, out uint processId);

public static Process GetShellProcess()
{
    try
    {
        var shellWindowHandle = GetShellWindow();

        if (shellWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(shellWindowHandle, out var shellPid);

            if (shellPid > 0)
            {
                return Process.GetProcessById((int) shellPid);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // ignored
    }

    return null;
}
```

And later on, use the same class to restart it with Restart Manager. It is better than `Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")[0]` anyway.

Comment: Thanks so much for sharing the gist! Unfortunately, this does not work with the current version of Windows 10 :( Running it left me in a bugged state where explorer was "stuck" between transitioning back. I lost all my open windows and had to manually kill off other explorer instances until I was back to a normal environment :(

Comment: I think relying on `GetProcessesByName` is the crux of the issue of the sample not working. We probably need to get a list of all the explorer processes, and then restart each of them.

Comment: It works on my system. Takes a little time (10sec?) but works. That being said you can use the `rm.RegisterProcessFile()` method and give full path of explorer (like in Ted example). It might change RM behavior. But giving the list doesn't matter as I copy the list and then provide RM before it does anything with an array of PIDs. Explorer was always tricky anyway. Try the file method tho before losing faith in RM.

Comment: I have also added more info to retrieve the main process of explorer. It might help in your case. In my case, I had no problem with multiple windows and through a long testing session as I was using it for one of my projects for the entire duration of today.